# Make Password NumericValidator Optional

Tags: python, django

For this application I'm working on, the password field should be able to accept only numeric password because some special users will only have to use 4 digits number to login to their dashboard.

I commented out the `NumericPassowrdValidator`, but I got `KEYERROR - 'NAME'`. I checked the `contrib.auth.password_validator` code to see if I can add options and set either true or false to the `NumericValidator` similar to `MinimumLengthValidator`, but I can't find anything like that.

How do I avoid the `NumericValidator`? What am I missing?

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    #'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the validator you need to comment out (or delete) the entire dict, not just the NAME key:

```
# {
#     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
# },
```

Comment: Ohh my bad! I used """ """ to comment out the whole dict but got error, so I decided to use one # to comment out. Thanks! I need a good sleep. :(

Comment: `"""..."""` doesn't comment out the code, it turns it into a string. This will effectively comment out the code in some cases (e.g. `"""AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [...]"""`), but you can't do it for an individual password validator because `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` should be a list of dicts and does not accept strings.